# how to save output of tcptrack into a text file

Tags: linux, terminal, curses

How to dump output of tcptrack into a text file?
I have tried using grep and cut but the output screen of tcptrack is made with curses library and changes dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the source code and remove the ncurses library and simply use printf instead of printw or simply write data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ncurses-term` installed, that has a minimal description [`glasstty`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-glasstty):

```
glasstty|classic glass tty interpreting ASCII control characters,
        am,
        cols#80,
        bel=^G, clear=^L, cr=^M, cub1=^H, cud1=^J, ht=^I, kcub1=^H,
        kcud1=^J, nel=^M^J,
```

You could run `tcptrack` with that terminal description (setting `TERM=glasstty`) and eliminate all of the cursor-addressing.  That leaves a lot of backspaces, which could be eliminated by a further reduction 
eliminating the **`cub1`** capability (using [**`tic`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tic.1m.html) to compile the description of course).  The reduced description would tell ncurses to repaint the whole screen for each change, which sounds like what you are expecting.